# What does this error means ? Java

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I've got this error, i've searched but i coudn't find anything about it :

> ```
> /tmp/ccs51ync.o: In function `main':
> ```
>
> ccnh7mCr.i:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `Main::class$'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Here is my code :

```
package musique;

import java.util.Scanner;

class Musique {
    static String test = "";
    public static boolean Double(String n) {
        boolean match = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < n.length() - 1; i++) {
            char last = n.charAt(i);
            if (last == n.charAt(i + 1)) {
                match = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return match;
    }

    public static String recursv(String n) {
        test = "";
        if (Musique.Double(n)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n.length() - 1; i++) {

                char last = n.charAt(i);
                if (last != n.charAt(i + 1)) {
                    test += last;
                } else {
                    test += n.substring(i + 2);
                    System.out.println(test);
                    break;
                }
            }
            return recursv(Musique.test);
        } else {
            return n;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String notes;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        notes = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(Musique.recursv(notes));

    }
}
```

Comment: How are you compiling your code? What compiler do you use? Also note that `Double` is a bad and confusing name.

Comment: How are you running the program? using java -jar? Also paste the output of java -version.

Comment: How do you see that?

Comment: Try removing all the `Musique.` in your code

Comment: Type `java -version` in a command prompt window or shell and copy & paste the output.

Comment: This is a really strange error and I suspect that you're using a weird version of Java, or you are using some tool to convert your Java code to a native executable instead of a normal class file. Are you?

Comment: The Double method should be lowercase by convention.

Comment: I ran your code, and seems to be working just fine. Can you show how you are running it? Are you running it from the command line? if so what is the command you are giving?